# PowerShell to stop and disable a service. Reading the servers from a TXT file

Tags: powershell

I see some questions about this topic, but I cannot get it working

```
Get-Service -Name Spooler -ComputerName (Get-Content c:\tmp\scripts\Servers\iservers.txt) |
 Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service  -StartupType Disabled -whatif
```

The code executes for each server on the txt file, and stops de service, but not disable the service.

Any help to get it work and/or Troubleshooting???
Regards.

Comment: You have a `-whatif` switch at the end of your line, that's probably the reason.

Comment: You're assuming get-service is returning live wmi objects that stop-service and set-service can access the methods on.  I would use invoke-command instead.

Answer (score 4):

### How to approach this kind of problem

In automation, we **work up to complexity**, meaning you should start simply and then add on more features until you see where it breaks.

Right now, you're trying to do a bunch of operations in one single line:

1. Load a list of computers *and*
2. Reach out to the computers and Stop a service *and*
3. Also while doing this, set the service to not automatically start.

There are a lot of problems you can run into, like "what happens if these PCs aren't enabled for remoting", or "what if you need a different account to handle stopping or disabling a service".

When you're trying to figure it all out in one-line, you're in for a bad and frustrating time.

**How to fix it**

Start simply.  Start with one computer that's nearby and definitely turned on.

Begin with reading a service.  Can you even get this operation to run?

```
Get-Service -ComputerName SomePC123 Spooler


Status   Name               DisplayName                           
------   ----               -----------                           
Running  spooler            Print Spooler
```

If you run into an error, then first figure out how to be able to remote into that one PC and see if the Print Spooler is running.  *Then,* you will know what steps to deploy to all of your machines to prepare them for remoting.

Then, once you can check if a service is running, you can add on the next step, try to stop the service.

So your code would start to look like this:

```
$computers = get-content .\someTextFile.txt
forEach($computer in $computers){
   $service = Get-Service -ComputerName $computer Spooler
   "status of spooler on $computer is $($service.Status), with start type of $($service.StartType)"

   #todo, set start type to Disabled...

}
```

Eventually, you will have migrated each step out of the one-liner and you'll know where and *why* any given command is failing.  This is the way.

Comment: Great lesson when approaching any script specially for people new to PowerShell.